# How dos XHR's "readyState==3" work?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Here's the code snippet

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){ 
   if(xhr.readyState == 3){
      console.log("readyState response length " + xhr.response.length);
   }
}
```

And the console is

```
readyState response length: 3854 
readyState response length: 33214 
readyState response length: 35296
```

I don't know what's the timing of `onreadystatechange` firing, it does seems a bit related to the size of response,how does it work?

Comment: What difference does it make? You can't access the `responseText` in this state.

Answer (score 5):

> What is XHR `readyState=3`?

Having the [`readyState`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#dom-xmlhttprequest-readystate) with a value of `3` it means that the current state is `LOADING`.

> So when is a `readyStateChange` event for that state fired?

Whenever an asynchrounous request does switch to the LOADING state. That is especially [triggered by](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#infrastructure-for-the-send%28%29-method):

> Once the first byte (or more) of the response entity body has been received […] or If there is no response entity body […]
>   Then switch to the LOADING state.

So browsers are free to fire this event with readyState 3 when they receive bytes of the response. Some trigger it more often (at every buffer flush), other's dont. [The spec even says](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#event-xhr-readystatechange) for the `readystatechange` Event:

> The `readyState` attribute changes at some seemingly arbitrary times for historical reasons.